# Admob - Cordova admob pro banner android position issue

Tags: cordova, admob, ionic-framework

I have tried to implement admob for both ios and android but it is not working on android. Ios is working perfectly fine.

```
if (window.AdMob ){

                var admobid = ( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) ? adMobHelper.getAndroid() : adMobHelper.getIos();
                AdMob = window.AdMob;

                AdMob.createBanner({
                        adId: admobid.banner,
                        adSize:AdMob.SMART_BANNER,
                        position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
                        autoShow:true
                    },
                    function(){console.log("Success Ad");},
                    function(error){console.log("Error ad: "+error);}
                )
            }
```

For android, ad is showing up in the middle of the screen. I have tried on galaxy s3 and nexus 5, same behaviour on both devices.

Comment: I'm using `com.admob.google` plugin and not having any problem (although it hasn't the admob mediation integrated, you should do it in your admob account: it's taken from [here](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova)).

Comment: Resolved it by adding  overlap: true, in createBanner option

Comment: @AsifAlamgir, Your comment helped me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.install admob phonegap plugin

```
cordova plugin add admob
```

2. init admob plugin
   init plugin after deviceready event

   admob.initAdmob("admob banner ID","admob interstitial ID");

3.show admob ads

```
admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.BANNER,admob.Position.TOP_APP);//show banner at the top of app
```

banner position list

```
Position: {
        TOP_LEFT: 1,
        TOP_CENTER: 2,
        TOP_RIGHT: 3,
        MIDDLE_LEFT: 4,
        MIDDLE_CENTER: 5,
        MIDDLE_RIGHT: 6,
        BOTTOM_LEFT: 7,
        BOTTOM_CENTER: 8,
        BOTTOM_RIGHT: 9,
        TOP_APP:10,
        BOTTOM_APP:11
    }
```

ref:https://github.com/admob-google/admob-cordova